# How to give multiple file names in log4j2 configuration for java opts?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I am following this manual to configure log4j2 in my java application-
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

However I am facing issues in giving file path as I have two xml files-

```
SERVICE_NAME="mailServer"
SERVICE_HOME=${SERVICE_HOME:="/srv/osgi"}
SERVICE_CONF=${SERVICE_CONF:="${SERVICE_HOME}"}

SERVICE_LOG4J_FILE=${SERVICE_LOG4J_FILE:="${SERVICE_CONF}/${SERVICE_NAME}-log4j.xml"}
SERVICE_LOG4J_OPTS=${SERVICE_LOG4J_OPTS:="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:${SERVICE_LOG4J_FILE}"}
```

Now I also want to give location of log4j2.xml.

So Is it correct to give comma separated file names as follows-

```
 SERVICE_LOG4J_FILE=${SERVICE_LOG4J_FILE:="${SERVICE_CONF}/${SERVICE_NAME}-log4j.xml", "${SERVICE_CONF}/log4j2.xml"}
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct to use the comma separated paths as the docs states in the **Composite Configuration** section. However I didn't quite get what you are trying to do here. If it is to generate multiple different files why not use different appenders in your log4j2 (xml, properties, yaml, etc) file?

Comment: @JorgeCampos- In production environment, the file `mailServer-log4j.xml` is already there but the file `log4j2.xml` is recently added and I don't want to mess up things in case they go wrong.

Comment: If you added the log4j2.xml file in the project you don't need to worry with the old one "mailServer-log4j.xml" log4j will ignore it. Just make sure that it has the correct configurations (migrating from 1.x to 2.x), in order to do so use another environment (similar to production) to test it before deploy the new version, make sure it will work as expected and then deploy

Comment: yes I am doing the same in a different environment. The issue is that we are using `mailServer-log4j.xml` file in AWS environment by giving such command line options and need to add log4j2.xml as well for some daemon service log handling. So not sure how it will behave at AWS level. Checking in different env is the way I am going with.

Comment: As long as you added the log4j2.xml file in the right place in your project (in the classpath) it will be fine. Just make sure to remove the other one from the configurations since the configuration has bigger priority in the log4j file resolution finder

Answer (score 0):

### you can use it

```
# Root logger option

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DEBUG, file,console

# Console Appender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.console.Append=true

log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [ %M ]  ( %C )  %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# File Appender

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm

log4j.appender.file.Append=true

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [ %M ]  ( %C )  %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file.File=C:/log/SpringMain.log

log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

Comment: How to give properties file path in java options?